# VBA code to have each values selected from a multiselect dependent dropdown list in excel cell in separate adjacent cells

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown

I have created a multi-select dependent dropdown list in excel. When I select from the multi-select list, I could have every selected value in a single cell in a new line. However, I wanted to put each selection in an adjacent separate cell instead of cramming the values in one cell. For instance, when I select Male and Female from my dropdown list, I want Male to appear on the first cell and Female on the next cell below. I want to apply the code to only one column with the multi-select dropdown list. Does anyone have that code?

The code I am using currently is below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L9")) Is Nothing Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & vbNewLine & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, try to write some code yourself, then ask. Currently, you question looks more appropriate for a freelance service site.

Comment: What do you mean by "a multi-select dependent dropdown list"?

Comment: @FaneDuru I meant a dropdown list where you can select multiple values from the list without replacing the first selection.

Comment: I do not have any knowledge that such an object exists in Excel... Do you mean Data Validation list **in a cell**? And `Worksheet_Change` event having a piece of code to concatenate the previous selection(s) with the last one? If so, please post the event code you use and I will help you adapting it to return in different cells.

Comment: @FaneDuru, yes it is a data validation list. I edited my question and posted the code I am using currently. Please have a look at it.

Comment: OK. Now, each selection adds a new line  in the Data validation cell. Where do you want them appearing according to your need? Since the cell in discussion is "L9", where do you like them to appear? First one in "M9", next one in "M10", followed by "M11" and so on? Supposing that my understanding is correct, how would you like to restart the process? I mean, to clean all mentioned above cells in "M:M" column? Don't you care about this aspect?

Comment: @FaneDuru I need the first to appear at L9, the next L10 and so on.

Comment: I am afraid you answered a little too late... I already  updated the code as I explained in my previous comment. **L9 is the List Validated cell**! How should the code 'know' which is its first value to be maintained in "L9", if it will be changed each time you select from the list?  Being only one such a value, it will never know **when to start returning below the Data validated cell**. Please, try using the code I pasted. If you would reply earlier, I could explain what can be done and what cannot... Even, to imagine a more complicated version to deal with what you say **now**...

Comment: I edited my answer and placed a new version, doing what you required in your last column. Please, send some feedback after testing it...

Comment: @FanuDuru, It worked. Thank you so much. I just referenced the whole column instead of Range("L9") I put Range("L:L")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, test the next updated event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Oldvalue As String, Newvalue As String, lastRM As Long, mtch
'Application.EnableEvents = True 'useless code line
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L9")) Is Nothing Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else
        If Target.Value = "" Then
             Me.Range(Target.Offset(, 1), Target.Offset(, 1).End(xlDown)).ClearContents
             GoTo Exitsub
        Else
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            lastRM = Target.Offset(, 1).End(xlDown).row
            If lastRM = Me.rows.count Then
                If Target.Offset(, 1).Value <> "" Then
                      If Target.Offset(, 1).Value <> Target.Value Then
                            Target.Offset(1, 1).Value = Target.Value
                      End If
                Else
                    Target.Offset(, 1) = Target.Value
                End If
            Else
                mtch = Application.match(Target.Value, Me.Range(Target.Offset(, 1), Target.Offset(, 1).End(xlDown)), 0)
                If IsError(mtch) Then
                    Target.Offset(lastRM - Target.row + 1, 1) = Target.Value
                End If
            End If
          End If
  End If
End If
'Application.EnableEvents = True 'useless code line
Exitsub:
 Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

Please, test the next version, which will do what you required in your last comment (to return in column L:L, starting from L9, inclusive):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim Oldvalue As String, Newvalue As String, lastRM As Long, mtch

 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 On Error GoTo Exitsub
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L9")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
          GoTo Exitsub
    Else
          Application.EnableEvents = False
          If Target.Value = "" Then
               Me.Range(Target.Offset(1), Target.Offset(1).End(xlDown)).ClearContents
               GoTo Exitsub
          Else
               Newvalue = Target.Value
               Application.Undo
               Oldvalue = Target.Value
               lastRM = Target.End(xlDown).row
               If lastRM = Me.rows.count Then
                      If Oldvalue <> "" Then
                           Target.Offset(1).Value = Newvalue
                      End If
               Else
                      mtch = Application.match(Newvalue, Me.Range(Target, Target.End(xlDown)), 0)
                      If IsError(mtch) Then
                          Target.Offset(lastRM - Target.row + 1) = Newvalue
                      End If
              End If
              If Oldvalue <> "" Then
                    Target.Value = Oldvalue
              Else
                    Target.Value = Newvalue
              End If
          End If
    End If
 End If
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Exitsub:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. It worked!  Thank you so much for taking your time to solve this. The edited code did what I wanted.

Comment: @Jahayag Glad I could help! It is good to have in mind the next idea: When you place a question, it is recommended to check if from time to time and answer the clarification questions, if any... I like helping people and usually I can solve their problems, if I am able to understand them. Sometimes, I took these questions as challenges and try answering based on some assumptions, but  I am upset when I spent some time on a wrong question description and not receive feedback when I ask clarification questions.   I am not so patient as I want...

Comment: You are right! I am Sorry that I couldn't explain my question very well in the first post. There is no better joy than helping others. You should be grateful that you have that in you. And thank you for being patient with me.